# Robolectric - Could not load class: org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am configuring Robolectric for a project that uses multi dex. I am using Robolectric 3.0 RC3 which should support Multidex without throwing that "Multi dex installation failed" exception.

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3')
```

My sample test is in src/test/java/SandwichTest:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class SandwichTest {
  @Test
  public void firstTest() { }
}
```

I have a global configuration file to load ShadowMultiDex in src/test/resources called robolectric.properties per the instructions on the [Robolectric site](http://robolectric.org/configuring/):

```
shadows=org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex
```

When I run my sample SandwichTest, I get this exception:

```
Could not load class: org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load class: org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex
at org.robolectric.annotation.Config$Implementation.parseClass(Config.java:147)
```

It looks like Robolectric is finding my configuration file but is unable to load the ShadowMultiDex class. Attempting to add the shadow multi dex module to my gradle file manually:

```
 testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0-SNAPSHOT')
```

or

```
 testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex')
```

Causes "failed to resolve" issues during sync.

What steps am I missing to get this sample test to run?

Comment: `testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex')` where is your version? Please post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: Adding that line to my gradle file causes an error during sync. For sharing the whole build.gradle file, I'll reproduce the issue in a simple Hello World app in a bit. Hold tight!

Comment: You didnt add a version to that dependency.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried both org.robolectric:shadows-multidex and org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0-SNAPSHOT. Neither worked.

Comment: testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0') would be your best bet. You didn't add a version on to it. Also, it doesn't look like it is available: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/wiki/2.4-to-3.0-Upgrade-Guide. However, I found it here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/robolectric/shadows-multidex/.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows. That one does the trick, but now I'm seeing this exception when I run my tests: "Could not load class: org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex." Any thoughts?

Comment: `shadows=` is for custom shadows I believe. Try removing that.

Comment: Thanks @JaredBurrows! It now compiles and runs, but I'm getting the exception some people were seeing here: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1520. I tried to reproduce in a simple HelloWorld app but am unable to so I'm guessing my app code is doing something funky. Feel free to submit your recommendation (use version 3.0 and remove shadows=) as an answer. If you'd prefer, I can submit it as an answer. Cheers!

Comment: Do you mind if I make an answer?

Comment: @JaredBurrows - not at all! Please go ahead! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your question, I noticed you were missing a `version` on your `Gradle` dependency.

**You have:**

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex')
```

**You need:**

```
testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0')
```

**Actual Release:** https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/robolectric/shadows-multidex/

**You should remove the:**

```
shadows=org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMultiDex
```

from your `src/test/resources/robolectric.properties` file. That is used for `custom` Shadows.

Comment: Thanks Jared! Works great! Cheers!