# Robolectric No shadows modules found containing a org.robolectric.ShadowsAdapter

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I followed official tutorial to add robolectric to my existing android application. But when i'am trying to run a simple test i got an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No shadows modules found containing a org.robolectric.ShadowsAdapter
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.instantiateShadowsAdapter(Robolectric.java:223)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.getShadowsAdapter(Robolectric.java:48)
at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.<init>(ParallelUniverse.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at
......
```

Here is my test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 23)
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
    }
}
```

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.3"
}
```

Comment: have a look at this answer in case you are using multidex in your app http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573228/2736039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from:

`testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.3"`

to

`testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1.2"`

Comment: What is the fix in?

Comment: this fixes that exception with shadows, is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't know what is the cause. For me 3.1.3 works fine

Comment: I have been using it but when I updated the library it threw the same exception that is in the question, so the solution was to use that old version. Do you use any other dependency?